# How to set the width of the cell and allow it to take multiple lines?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a table below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Table title}\\
    \hline
    Fuze Type & Weight & Muzzle Velocity & From sea level\\
    \hline
    Time & Vehicle wt: 5000

    Tyre wt: 100&40000 m/s & 0m\\
    \hline
    Degrees & Minutes & Mil &Range in m & Time of flight in s\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

1. I want the second column to be of fixed width and if the length of text in this column is more, text will be allowed to take multiple lines without changing the width.
   Edit:Can you also tell me how to do the same in longtable.(|>{\centering}p{2cm}| doesn't seem to work in longtable.
2. I want left and right edges of the top row visible.
3. I need the last columns of rows 2 and 3 invisible(no borders), since there is no data in those cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}|c|c|c|}
    \cline{1-4}
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Table title}\\
    \cline{1-4}
    Fuze Type & Weight & Muzzle Velocity & From sea level\\
    \cline{1-4}
    \centering
    Time & Vehicle wt: 5000

    Tyre wt: 100&40000 m/s & 0m\\
    \hline
    Degrees & Minutes & Mil &Range in m & Time of flight in s\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

To get a column that wraps, you need to use the `p` column type.  To make that column be centred, you need to use the `array` package.  To get the vertical lines on empty cells you need to put the column separator `&` to mark the cells, not simply end a row with `\\`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{2cm}|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Table title} \\
\hline
Fuze Type & Weight & Muzzle Velocity & From sea level &\\
\hline
Time & Vehicle wt: 5000

Tyre wt: 100&40000 m/s & 0m &\\
\hline
Degrees & Minutes & Mil &Range in m & Time of flight in s\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{2cm}|c|c|c|}
\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Table title} \\
\cline{1-4}
Fuze Type & Weight & Muzzle Velocity & From sea level \\
\cline{1-4}
Time & Vehicle wt: 5000

Tyre wt: 100&40000 m/s & 0m \\
\hline
Degrees & Minutes & Mil &Range in m & Time of flight in s\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Normally the title would be a caption to the table, rather than a row in itself.  You can do this by wrapping the whole `tabular` in a `table` environment, and adding a `\caption{Title}` command.

Many people think that vertical lines in tables are not good form; take a look a the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package for very nice looking tables without vertical lines.

**Addendum**

Sorry I didn't read your request as carefully, since the resultant table looks quite odd.  But I've added a second table matching your actual request.

[image]

Comment: @Vinod: change `tabular` to `longtable` and load package `longtable`, that's all

Answer (score 2):

choose a greater baselineskip, makes the table looks nicer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{3cm}|c|c|c}\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Table title}\\\cline{1-4}
 Fuze Type & Weight & Muzzle Velocity & From sea level\\\cline{1-4}
    Time & Vehicle wt: 5000
    Tyre wt: 100&40000 m/s & 0m\\\hline
    Degrees & Minutes & Mil &Range in m 
           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Time of flight in s}\\\hline
  \end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]